# Index Match W/ Two Criteria Displaying Highest Result

Tags: excel

I have an index match array using two criteria retrieving result but haven't figured out how to only get the highest result.

The formula is:

```
INDEX(MAIN!$C$1:MAIN!$C$2000,MATCH($H$2&A12,MAIN!$A$1:MAIN!$A$2000&MAIN!$B$1:MAIN!$B$2000,0))
```

H2 in this example would be 20-May and A12 is LASV

The sample list within the MAIN! sheet:

[image]

In this example I want it to look up LASV and 20-May and only list number 6 in column C.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is part of the actual list:

[image]

Comment: @pnuts it would not necessarily always be on the buttom. I will add a portion of the actual list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this instance INDEX/MATCH is the wrong tool.

If you have Office 365 Excel then use MAXIFS():

```
=MAXIFS(C:C,A:A,"LASV",B:B,DATE(2018,5,20))
```

If not you can use AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,$C$1:$C$4/(($A$1:$A$4="LASV")*($B$1:$B$4=DATE(2018,5,20))),1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, Scott. My list has a variety of different values in Column A and B, would this work? So, for example, Column A would also have SANFR, LA, NJ etc and B would have a variety of dates.

Comment: This will only find the max based on the criteria you provide, even if there are other entries that do not meet the criteria.

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks for your help, Scott! Just in case, I have added a portion of the actual list.

Comment: your new data the "Dates" do not look like dates but text strings.

Comment: I just wanted to thank you again. It works like a charm! :)